# How does speeding up / slowing down audio with FFMpeg work technically?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I've been looking into FFmpeg's tools for speeding up and slowing down portions of video using their built in filters (such as [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)). For video speed filtering it discusses a little bit about you can change the PTS of each video frame to affect its playback rate, but how is this similarly done for audio?